# Function Split PHP not working with given pattern

Tags: php, split

I need to split this (PHP)

```
$var = XXXXXX31,72YYYYYY32,73DDDDDD33,74
```

to result

```
[0] => XXXXXX31,72
[1] => YYYYYY32,73
[2] => DDDDDD33,74
```

I am using function preg_split

with pattern `('/(?=[a-z]+)(?<=[0-9])/i',$var);`

But it is returning

```
[0] => 31,72
[1] => XXXXXX32,73
[2] => YYYYYY33,74
[3] => DDDDDD
```

Comment: Your input doesn't match your expected output (or actual output). Please share actual running code.

Comment: What is the splitting rule? It seems you need to split it in fixed size chunks. If this is true then [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is the function you need.

Comment: i fixed my question, read again please.

Comment: @user1629045 Your input still doesn't match your expected output. Please use actual values you've tested yourself.

Comment: i already tried  pattern ('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$var);

Comment: i want  result [0] => XXXXXX31,77
[1] => YYYYYY32,77
[2] => DDDDDD33,77

Comment: but it is resulting [0] => 31,77
[1] => XXXXXX32,77
[2] => YYYYYY33,77
[3] => DDDDDD

Comment: @user1629045 I've tried to answer your question, but it's really frustrating that you still haven't provided valid input and output. (Your input has 5 Xs, but your expected output somehow has 6.)

Comment: i will fizx the question

Answer (score 0):

I've made assumptions about how you actually want to split the string. If this isn't what you want, you'll have to tell us what behavior you actually intended.

```
$input = "TIPO DISCRIMINAÇÃO PRAZO VALOR1.923,11VENCIMENTO BASICORENDIMENTOS230,77ANUENIO - ART.244, LEI 8112/900013.596,99GRATIFICACAO NATALINA93,65FGR-FUNC GRATIFICADA L 8216/91155,46GRAT.DESEMP.FUNCAO-GADF LD.13368,58AUXILIO-TRANSPORTE955,20GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT238,80GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT0011.568,44ADIANT.GRATIF.NATALINA/ATIVO123,45";
$matches = [];

preg_match_all("/.*?[\\d.]+,\\d{2}/", $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);

// Output:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => TIPO DISCRIMINAÇÃO PRAZO VALOR1.923,11
//     [1] => VENCIMENTO BASICORENDIMENTOS230,77
//     [2] => ANUENIO - ART.244, LEI 8112/900013.596,99
//     [3] => GRATIFICACAO NATALINA93,65
//     [4] => FGR-FUNC GRATIFICADA L 8216/91155,46
//     [5] => GRAT.DESEMP.FUNCAO-GADF LD.13368,58
//     [6] => AUXILIO-TRANSPORTE955,20
//     [7] => GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT238,80
//     [8] => GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT0011.568,44
//     [9] => ADIANT.GRATIF.NATALINA/ATIVO123,45
// )
```

Comment: not work... please hep me to separate this string [0] => XXXXXX1.923,11YYYYY230,77 to 1.923,11YYYYYY

Comment: It *does* work... I just ran it. If it's not doing what you want with the actual data you have, you *really* need to tell us what data you're using and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: separate this string [0] => XXXXXX1.923,11YYYYYY230,77 to 1.923,11YYYYYY

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => TIPO DISCRIMINAÇÃO PRAZO VALOR1.923,11
    [1] => VENCIMENTO BASICORENDIMENTOS230,77
    [2] => ANUENIO - ART.244, LEI 8112/900013.596,99
    [3] => GRATIFICACAO NATALINA93,65
    [4] => FGR-FUNC GRATIFICADA L 8216/91155,46
    [5] => GRAT.DESEMP.FUNCAO-GADF LD.13368,58
    [6] => AUXILIO-TRANSPORTE955,20
    [7] => GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT238,80
    [8] => GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT0011.568,44
    [9] => ADIANT.GRATIF.NATALINA/ATIVO
)

Comment: my array is like this.... but the value from array position number 1 is on position 0,

Comment: @user1629045 Is that an example of input or output? (I thought the input was a string and the output was meant to be an array.)

Comment: this is an output.... the input is "TIPO DISCRIMINAÇÃO PRAZO VALOR1.923,11VENCIMENTO BASICORENDIMENTOS230,77ANUENIO - ART.244, LEI 8112/900013.596,99....."

Comment: @user1629045 Does every string end with a comma and then two digits?

Comment: @user1629045 Actually, I can see that the last element in this example doesn't have any numbers at the end at all. Is that another typo, or is that actually valid input? What would the string look like if there was another element after that? E.g. "...ADIANT.GRATIF.NATALINA/ATIVOGDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT0011.568,44..." How would you know to split between "/ATIVO" and "GDPGPE"?

Comment: @user1629045 One more edit attempt, making the assumption that your data above just had a typo in it. (I added "123,45" to the end.)

Comment: What do you **want** to happen?

Comment: // Output:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1.923,11VENCIMENTO BASICORENDIMENTOS
//     [1] => 230,77ANUENIO - ART.244, LEI 8112/90001
//     [2] => 3.596,99GRATIFICACAO NATALINA
//     [3] => 93,65FGR-FUNC GRATIFICADA L 8216/91
//     [4] => 155,46GRAT.DESEMP.FUNCAO-GADF LD.13
//     [5] => 368,58AUXILIO-TRANSPORTE
//     [6] => 955,20GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT
//     [7] => 238,80GDPGPE - LEI 11.784/2008 AT001
//     [8] => 1.568,44ADIANT.GRATIF.NATALINA/ATIVO
//     [9] => 123,45
// )

Comment: @user1629045 That has absolutely nothing to do with the question you asked originally. I've wasted enough time with this.

Comment: the problem is that the value is on last array

Answer (score 0):

here you go Try this + there is a typo in your input, i think you meant to have 6 X's instead of 5.

```
$var = 'XXXXX31,77YYYYYY32,77DDDDDD33,77';
$array = explode('77',$var);
$array = array_filter($array); // remove empty elements

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $array[$i] .= '77';
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => XXXXX31,77
    [1] => YYYYYY32,77
    [2] => DDDDDD33,77
)
```

Comment: It's hard to know, since the original question doesn't specify the goal, but my guess is that this produces the wrong output when the input is `"XXXXXX76,77YYYYYY77,77"`.

Comment: aha you are right it's not fully functional but let's us hear from him

Comment: 77 variate sorry.;... this is a value that changes everytime after commas